# Column chart not showing series properly in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have the following charts where the series data is an array of config objects:

`enter code herehttp://jsfiddle.net/AANAB/`

http://jsfiddle.net/AANAB/1/

Try changing the chart type to pie.If you observe now three series will be shown.Why does the column chart consider this as one series and the pie chart as 3 series? My requirement is to be able to render the column chart and pie chart as three separate series for the same given data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost thing,
pie and column are 2 completely different types of charts.

column can be said as a graph, and pie as a chart.

column chart has 2 axes namely x and y while pie is distributing the area proportionally.

there is no mistake in this one. they are rendered properely.

For pie chart the structure accepted is 
{
name: name of the slice,
y: value of the slice
}

each slice has its own name like the xAxis categories we provide for column chart.
the Y has the value is common for all the highcharts.

so here what i recommend is to maintain the datasets differently for both column and pie to get what you have required.

Answer (score 0):

All works properly, in pie chart you have different colours, only, so you can set the same color then you achieve the same effect as in columns.

Comment: what I wanted to achieve was , for a given categories data set, the pie and column chart must appear the same (i.e. in three different colors and 3 different series). I know the different colors for column can be achieved using colorByPoint as follows [link]http://jsfiddle.net/AANAB/2/  , however, it is still shown as only one series in the legend. So as @strikers pointed out, for a pie chart each category narrows down to a slice or point. But in all other charts the data provided in on per series basis. So my requirement may not be possible to achieve.Please correct me if I am wrong.